# Material UI TextField React Component Conditional style don't trigger textField render

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

React Component :

```
class Info extends Component {
    constructor() {
       this.state = {
        editAccount: false
       }
       this.changeTrue = this.changeTrue.bind(this);
       this.changeFalse = this.changeFalse.bind(this);
    }
    changeTrue() {
      this.setState({ediAccount: true}
    }
    changeFalse() {
      this.setState({ediAccount: false}
    }
    render() {
        const specific_style = this.state.editAccount ? { background: 'red'} : { background : 'yellow' }
        return (
         <div>
            <TextField
                id='first_name'
                inputStyle={ specific_style}
                value={this.state.first_name}
              />
           <button onClick={this.changeTrue}>Click True</button>
           <button onClick={this.changeFalse}>Click False</button>
         </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Having this component and editAccount having the state changed doesn't rerender apply the style changes? Doesn't rerender the TextField ? Anybody knows why ?

Comment: Where does `editAccount` come from? `red` and `yellow` should be strings. You forgot to close your `TextField` component with `/>`. Please correct these issues.

Comment: Many pieces are missing from your code. Can you please post complete code?

Comment: Again a comment, since not sure if it's a typo in your code or here : `this.setState({ediAccount: true}`

Answer (score 1):

> [State Updates May Be Asynchronous](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous)
>
> React may batch multiple `setState()`
>   calls into a single update for performance.
>
> Because `this.props` and `this.state` may be updated asynchronously, you
>   should not rely on their values for calculating the next state.

When updating the state based on the current state always use a callback in the call to `setState()`. The callback gets the previous state and returns the next state. This is because react may batch multiple calls to `setState()` thus not using a callback will override previous calls:

```js
this.setState(prevState => ({editAccount: !prevState.editAccount)});
```

Also in your object that contains the styles you used variables (which you did not define) instead of strings:

```js
const specific_style = this.state.editAccount ? { background: red /* red is not defined*/} : { background : yellow /* same here */ };
```

It should probably be:

```js
const specific_style = this.state.editAccount ? { background: 'red' } : { background : 'yellow' };
```

Objects can't be written like css classes.

The fully working code has to look about like this:

```
class Info extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      editAccount: false
    };

    this.changeStyle = this.changeStyle.bind(this);
  }

  changeStyle() {
    this.setState(state => ({editAccount: !state.editAccount}));
  }

  render() {
    const specific_style = this.state.editAccount ? { background: 'red' } : { background: 'yellow' };
    return (
      <div>
        <TextField
          id="first_name"
          inputStyle={specific_style}
        />
        <button onClick={this.changeStyle}>Toggle red/yellow</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

See this [working codesandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/oxy0lw75wz).

Comment: The styles where correct and updated the state changing. Still happening.

Comment: @NicuIonutCampian And what about the typo in your calls to `setState()`? You wrote `ediAccount` instead of `editAccount`.

Comment: my bad on type that would trigger me a runtime error and i could fix that. That is not the issue. I've took a look into the TextField Class from Material-ui and there is no condition for rerender the TextField component in case the styles are changed.

Comment: @NicuIonutCampian No this typo wouldn't result in a runtime error. You are setting the name of a key of the style object there. You will end up having an object with both the keys `ediAccount` and `editAccount` like this: `{editAccount: false, ediAccount: true}` with `ediAccount` not being used anywhere. Also the `style` prop is nothing that needs to be implemented. Every react component has it by default and a change of it always triggers a re-render. Please make sure your code does not contain any trivial errors before posting it here.

Comment: @NicuIonutCampian I mean the state object, not the style object. My bad.

Comment: @NicuIonutCampian I made a small codesandbox examle where you can see that it works flawlessly: https://codesandbox.io/s/oxy0lw75wz. Also another issue of your code is that your `constructor()` does not call `super()` with the `props`.

Answer (score 0):

It appears you forgot to put '<' and '/>' within the return of your render function. Two of us made edits to resolve this but perhaps thats also the issue

Comment: It was a fast mock class implementation, the component is written oke.

Comment: Then might I suggest posting a more complete implementation.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to use a lifecycle method like `componentWillReceiveProps` to force a re-render. Also - format your code

Comment: How would that help on state changes? react doesn't need to be forced to re-render, when props or state changes.

Answer (score 0):

Where / How is `editAccount` defined ? It should come from the `state` or the `props` to trigger the re-render.

If the `render()` method isn't affected by the `props` / `state` changes, it isn't triggered.

Comment: IMO,Rather than making it an answer, this can better be a comment.

Comment: The rerender method is triggered but the TextField doesn't take new styles. Probably the TextField component render() doesn;t get triggered. But why ?

Comment: @NicuIonutCampian You used the undefined variables `red` and `yellow` in your style object. This should probably be the strings `'red'` and `'yellow'` instead?